# CKeditor 5 (online builder) insist on having placeholder in the text field

Tags: placeholder, ckeditor5

Using the default setup using the CKeditor v5 online builder and it works, but I have a minor challenge.

The text area insist on having placeholder text inside the area. I have looked into the documentation but there is no ay to set it to false.

The actual html code does not include a placeholder-tag, so it's not to blame. Sere the attached screenshot which (sorry in Danish) includes 2 placeholders in the main text area. I have not enabled it anywhere, so why are they showing?

When inspecting the elements in a browser, there are 2 (one with the big letters and another one with the smaller letters)

[image: the text area with placeholders]

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You could do the following to remove the title plugin and set the placeholder to blank:

```
ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '.editor' ), {
  removePlugins: ['Title'],
  placeholder: '',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess that I solved the issue my self all though it is not very logic.

I had included a plugin named 'title'.

"..Enables support for adding the title field to your document. It helps ensure that there will always be a single title field at the beginning of the document..."

All though the plugin was added I did not actively activate the function anywhere. Nor did I find any syntax to enable or disable the function. I just appeared with no option to change that.

Anyhow. I made a new package using the CKeditor 5 Online Builder and I did not select the 'title' plugin and everything was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the placeholder in the CKEditor using this:

```
config = {
    toolbar: [
      'heading',
      ],
    removePlugins: ['Title'],
  }
```